# Java "logical vs bitwise operator" cleanup

Tags: discussion, questions, canonical

We have these:

- [Difference between & and &&](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564410/difference-between-and)
- [Differences in boolean operators: & vs && and | vs ||](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014535/differences-in-boolean-operators-vs-and-vs)
- [Why do we usually use `||` not `|`, what is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101992/why-do-we-usually-use-not-what-is-the-difference)

And possibly more. I'm referring to questions such as the above three that serve as the endpoint in a lot of duplicate chains.

These are all essentially the same question but worded slightly differently.

I didn't want to start dupe hammering things because I really couldn't decide; but I *do* feel that 3 (or more) canonical questions for this is 2 (or more) too many.

Does anybody have any clean up ideas? Can we perhaps merge them all together? Or create a new question that just clearly answers all of these and use *that*?

Comment: [First](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564410/difference-between-and) and [Thrid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101992/why-do-we-usually-use-not-what-is-the-difference) questions have good answers. I would prefer the Third one. So, I think it is better to mark other two as duplicate of the third question though it is older.

Comment: Don't the documentation explain this? Wasn't Oracle supposed to write good documentation?

Comment: @Braiam The unfortunate truth is that reproducing easily accessible documentation tends to be the recipe for SO's most frequently viewed questions and highest voted answers, despite the tool tip on the downvote button. It's a fact we just have to come to terms with. For example, as a general rule of thumb in [tag:java], if you need a quick internet point boost, [just quote the JLS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8710685/616460).

Answer (score 3):

It feels like [Differences in boolean operators: & vs && and | vs ||](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014535/differences-in-boolean-operators-vs-and-vs) is the stronger question, and the better duplicate target, since several answers cover both `&` and `|` in detail.

I'm not so convinced that we really *need* a merge, since these answers are effectively repeating themselves, but out of the three, the question above seems to cover all of them best.

Comment: I tend to agree; my only issue with that one was the answer didn't really talk about the logical operators that much; it mentioned them but it focused more on "what are the bitwise operators" rather than "what is the difference". For example, the answers there wouldn't clearly help the OP in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39692690/writing-a-conditional-statement (which is what prompted me to find all these to begin with). For that I chose http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564410/difference-between-and; although that one doesn't cover OR. All of these are missing exactly one thing.

Comment: @JasonC:  I wonder if we're trying to shoehorn a solution there.  That particular question had other glaring errors *besides* the use of the bitwise AND, and I feel like there's no real harm in a fuller answer which encompasses that as opposed to a one-stop-shop duplicate.